# One test suite for functional and performance test

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have been playing around watir-webdriver-performance gem of late and I am quiet interested to test the functionality and performance of the website using single test suite.

Thanks to Alister Scott for [this](http://watirmelon.com/2011/07/19/easily-capturing-response-time-metrics-using-the-watir-webdriver-performance-gem/)

Now I want to include this into my env.rb file and run after each scenario.
Any inputs in this regards would be of great help.

Comment: I believe the performance gem can only get the performance results from the current page. Running just at the end of each scenario, might not make sense depending on what your scenario is.

Comment: @JustinKo Sorry, I may have framed my question right. But I want to calculate the performance metrics for each page load.

Comment: Depending on how you have setup your code, you might find Alister Scott's follow-up article useful - http://watirmelon.com/2011/08/10/capturing-page-performance-times-with-my-watirmeloncucumber-framework/